# perl - printing on screen periodically without sleep()

Tags: multithreading, perl, time, intervals, periodic-task

I have been coding with perl and I am doing some calculations, which are taking some time in a long for loop... Size of the loop is given by the user.

So in every ten seconds or so, I want to print some info on screen, without using sleep function, because there are other things going on and I don't want to waste time on sleep function.

Any ideas?

Comment: I usually add something to a long loop - for example `if(loopCounter % 10000 == 0) printf(".");` . Translate this to your favorite language / situation. One extra statement per loop is usually not a big thing. If it is, you could make a 10k loop inside a bigger loop and print when you get to the outer loop (for zero per-loop overhead).

Comment: yeah I also thought about it but for not is my worst solution. I want to print in periodic time intervals not periodic processes.

thanks though

Comment: Then instead of counting iterations, check whether the clock has wrapped at some digit. Would be a bit slower...

Comment: you mean checking time in each iteration of loop or something else?

the thing is, code is really short and fast; so I dont want to make it slower by adding extra control loops or other parameters but I am also depressed for a way out..

Comment: A well implemented `sleep()` function in its own thread should consume "no" resources. But the key is "in its own thread".

Comment: yeah i am also thinking that will be my best solution...

should i use a async thread or normal one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
use threads;

async {
  my $i = 0;
  LOOP: {
    print $i++, "\n";
    sleep 10;
    redo LOOP;
  }
};

# rest of program..
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to print something in a long loop after every five seconds, you can do something like this (pseudocode but you get the idea):

```
tLast = currentTime modulo interval

for (some long loop):
  tNow = currentTime modulo interval
  if tNow < tLast:
    print "something"
  tLast = tNow
  doSomethingElse
```

If the loop is quite tight and this would add too much overhead, do

```
for (some long loop):
  tNow = currentTime modulo interval
  if tNow < tLast:
    print "something"
  tLast = tNow
  for(some tight loop):
     doSomethingElse
```

Now the checking of the time happens "only every so often" - so no overhead for the tightest loop, only for the less-tight outer loop (this is in essence a combination of what I proposed in my first comment, and what I proposed in a later one).

Comment: The second version should not slow you down at all. Time checking only happens as often as you want it (every 10th, 100th, 1000th… depending on how tight your inner loop is, this can have "zero" impact on performance).

Answer (score 1):

Usually it's not a problem. Because you have a progress of your job. Relying on this progress you can occasionally print something.

But if you want to print exactly every 10 seconds it's probably better to use another thread to print the progress to user every 10 seconds and `sleep()` function.

Also you could deal with clock directly i.e. keep `startTime` and calculate `currentTime` if their `differenceInSeconds % 10 == 0` then print something.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Smart::Comments](https://metacpan.org/pod/Smart%3a%3aComments) to produce a progress bar.

```
use Smart::Comments;
use Time::HiRes qw(usleep);
### process started
for my $n (0..1000000) { ### Initializing...  done
    usleep 5; #...simulate work...
}
### process ended
1;
```

Which would produce:

```
### process started
Initializing..............     done
```

Comment: this sounds great BUT my code runs in threads - up to several k's depending on the user input-   how does it work with threats?

lets say 5 threats runing a for loop... it is the same loop being run by different threats... what would I see in the bar than?